# What is the likely definition of a women's "'health' west" from 1891?

Tags: meaning, history

In an 1891 newspaper advertisement (published in Manitoba, Canada) there is a reference to "wool 'health' wests in girls and ladies" which on first glance looks like a spelling error but is repeated in other ads in the same year. Unfortunately, this is a very difficult combination of simple words to search for, does anyone have a reference for a definition of this garment term?

[image: Scan of original advertisement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost sure to be a misspelling of *vest*. In the nineteenth century, at least in London, /v/ and /w/ were either interchangeable, or they were replaced by a sound in between. Witness Sam Weller.

Comment: A misspelling may be likely, but it appeared to be deliberate use of an alternate spelling. I was curious as to whether there might have been a reason, like success versus succefs indicating an upper class eduction for a Hudson's Bay trader.

Comment: @moberley: Misspelling is perhaps the wrong word. Phonetic spelling might be more accurate. I know nothing of the accents of Hudson's Bay traders, but might not that 'f' be  a long 's'?

Comment: I don't have a written reference, but I learned that detail from someone who worked at Parks Canada playing a mid-19th century gentlemen. The dialect coach taught him to pronounce that particular spelling to sound historically appropriate. I mentioned it because the spelling choice indicated information about the writer (such as class). I thought perhaps the spelling choice in the advertisement might carry some added information as well.

Comment: By the way, did you intend to type "Witness" rather than "Wintess"?

Comment: I did, and thanks for pointing it out. Now corrected. (I've had to explain elsewhere that I'm having to type with one hand bandaged at the moment, which may in part account for it.)

Comment: +1 for the sake of Pickwick as the barrister said to the old dowager when he saw your post on the Internet.

Comment: What about the 'health' part?

Comment: Regarding v/w, also consider Wagner and Piggly Viggly. Meanwhile, could "health vest" be a strange euphemism for "corset?"

Comment: @fluffy: That seems more than likely.

Answer (score 3):

*Oxford English Dictionary*, under "vest" does list the spelling "west" from the  17th century as dialect.  From 1712:

> Payd for mackin a west and briches for gouddins child, [£]0. 1. 6.

Answer (score 1):

While *west* might be an alternative spelling for *vest*, it might also be a local or regional term for *weskit* or *waistcoat* (which at the time was typically pronounced "weskit"), formed as a sort of contraction of *weskit*, or a blending of *vest* and *weskit*.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Health" part of the name:

In this era there was a theory that sweating was good for the health.  Ballplayers used to train in wool uniforms to get in some sweating.  This might be the reason for the 'health', as a wool vest would be considerably warmer than lighter fabrics.

It could also just be warmer to avoid colds and chills.